# How to check the schema of DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the DataFrame `df` with some data that is the result of the calculation process. Then I store this DataFrame in the database for further usage.

For example:

```
val rowsRDD: RDD[Row] = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Row("first", 2.0, 7.0),
    Row("second", 3.5, 2.5),
    Row("third", 7.0, 5.9)
  )
)

val schema = new StructType()
  .add(StructField("id", StringType, true))
  .add(StructField("val1", DoubleType, true))
  .add(StructField("val2", DoubleType, true))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rowsRDD, schema)
```

I would need to check that all columns in the final DataFrame correspond to specific data types. Of course, one way is to create a DataFrame using schema (as an above example). However, in some cases the changes can be occasionally introduced to the data types during the calculation process - after the initial DataFrame was created (for example, when some formula applied to DataFrame was changed).

Therefore, I want to double-check that the **final** DataFrame corresponds to the initial schema. If it does not correspond, then I would like to apply the corresponding casting. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the schema of a dataframe with the schema method

```
df.schema // Or `df.printSchema` if you want to print it nicely on the standard output
```

Define a castColumn method

```
def castColumn(df: DataFrame, colName: String, randomDataType: DataType): DataFrame =
    df.withColumn(colName, df.col(colName).cast(randomDataType))
```

Then apply this method to all the columns you need to cast.

First, get an Array of tuples with the colName and the targeted dataType

```
//Assume your dataframes have the same column names, you need to sortBy in case the it is not in the same order

// You can also iterate through dfOrigin.schema only and compare their dataTypes with target dataTypes instead of zipping

val differences = (dfOrigin.schema.fields.sortBy{case (x: StructField) => x.name} zip dfTarget.schema.fields.sortBy{case (x: StructField) => x.name}).collect {
                   case (origin: StructField, target: StructField) if origin.dataType != target.dataType => 
                        (origin.name, target.dataType)
}
```

Then

```
 differences.foldLeft(df) {
      case (acc, value) => castColumn(acc, value._1, value._2)
 }
```

Comment: What is `differences`?

Comment: Updated, does this help you? (I might write the code to calculate val differences if you need to.)

Comment: I appreciate if you can show how to calculate `differences`.

Comment: Added some precisions and different ways to calculate differences

Comment: In 2022, to print schema, you can use ```df.info```, as the mentioned method does not work now.

Comment: @Vishnu do you have any references? As of Spark 3.3.0 I still see `schema` and `printSchema`. cf [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html). And I don't see the `info` method

Comment: @BlueSheepToken sorry, I was looking for python when came across this post.

Answer (score 17):

Based on Untyped Dataset Operations from https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html, it should be:

`df.printSchema()`

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- val1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- val2: double (nullable = true)
```

This prints the schema in a tree format.Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but how can I change the schema if it's needed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. If you want to "check the schema of DataFrame" like the OP question, this is better than `df.schema` for readability and so the results don't get truncated.

Comment: Actually, I think OP asked to check "programmatically" the schema. Not on the standard output

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the following example illustrates how to revert a DataFrame with changed column types to its original version:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "a", 100L, 10.0), (2, "b", 200L, 20.0)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val df2 = Seq(
  (1, "a", 100, 10.0f), (2, "b", 200, 20.0f)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

df2.printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c4: float (nullable = false)

val fieldsDiffType = (df1.schema.fields zip df2.schema.fields).collect{
  case (a: StructField, b: StructField) if a.dataType != b.dataType =>
    (a.name, a.dataType)
}
// fieldsDiffType: Array[(String, org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)] =
//   Array((c3,LongType), (c4,DoubleType))

val df2To1 = fieldsDiffType.foldLeft(df2)( (accDF, field) =>
  accDF.withColumn(field._1, col(field._1).cast(field._2))
)

df2To1.printSchema
// root
//  |-- c1: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- c2: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- c3: long (nullable = false)
//  |-- c4: double (nullable = false)
```

Note that this solution works only if the DataFrame columns remain the same in size and order, and does not cover types such as Array or Struct.

[UPDATE]

If there is concern that column order might be changed, you can first order `df1.schema.fields` and `df2.schema.fields` before performing `zip`:

```
df1.schema.fields.sortBy(_.name) zip df2.schema.fields.sortBy(_.name)
```

Comment: If the number of fields and names are same but not in order, how will you change the code?

Comment: @stack0114106, please see my expanded answer.